# Key bindings For Doom Emacs

Tags: key-bindings, doom

I am trying to start using Doom Emacs, but I find it increasingly difficult to find what the new key bindings are for certain tasks, like the ones for using Org Mode.

When I use vanilla Emacs, there is the documentation for every tasks, so how do people using other distributions, like Doom Emacs, find what all the new key bindings are?

For example Org Mode has hundreds of key bindings, are all these remapped to new ones for Doom? How do I find them?

Comment: I don't know Doom, but in Spacemacs there are two ways: use the menus that pop up at the bottom of the screen (e.g. after typing `SPC` in Evil mode), or search by the name of the function you want to run (`SPC SPC` in Evil mode), and take note of the parenthetical keybindings.

Comment: There is a third way: look at the source code. I know that's annoying though.

Answer (score 8):

**To describe a key sequence**

`SPC h k` runs `helpful-key` and will describe what the key sequence does in the current context. This will take the full key sequence, e.g. `SPC h k` then `g g` , and describe what the key sequence does (in this case, run `evil-goto-first-line`)

**To show the key sequence for a known function**

`M-x <function name>`

**To see all keybinds**

`SPC h b b` runs `counsel-descbinds` and will show all defined keys and their definitions.

**To see all keybinds for a major mode**

For a specific major mode map, `SPC h b f` will prompt you for a major mode (e.g. `org-mode-map`) and then show the associated keybinds.